# How may I close the small window for cookies, without making any choice?

Tags: support

What are the classes of cookies after clicking Customize Settings used for?

Sometimes it doesn't proceed after clicking Customize Settings.

How may I close the small window for cookies, without making any choice?

[image]

Comment: "What are the classes of cookies after clicking Customize Settings used for?": does https://stackoverflow.com/legal/cookie-policy (the URL "Cookie Policy" points to) answer this? "Sometimes it doesn't proceed after clicking Customize Settings": are you turning JavaScript on/off somehow? That button doesn't work when JavaScript is off.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I dismiss the new cookie popup that appears on the site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362697)